# angular doesn't work after render body using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have render a html page using ajax. This is my html

```
<div class="contents" id="subContents" ng-app="">
    @RenderBody()
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and this is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#sideMenuCustomerDivition").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#subContents').load('Default/subView');
   });
});
```

In rendering view i have try to use angular functions. But it couldn't works after render body using ajax.

Comment: because `Default/subView` is not $compiled with angularjs Controllers $scope, try using `ng-include` instead.

Comment: where did i use ng-include

Comment: View my answer below, or this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YGd0lxfFraWiADwjXkaA?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this task in angular way, forget everything about `jQuery` and just think of angularjs.

**Angular**

```
var app = angular.module('demo', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name ="World!";
  $scope.someVar = 'This is controller content';

  $scope.applyTemplate = function() {

    $scope.template = "mytemplate.html";
  }
});
```

**Markup**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <button ng-click="applyTemplate()">Load Template </button>

    <div ng-include="template" ng-if="template"></div>
  </body>
```

Better view this live demo [in Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YGd0lxfFraWiADwjXkaA?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Why you using Ajax to render the site? You can use a routing extension for angular. ui-router or angular router. Its better to use angular without jQuery

Comment: Answers aren't the best place to ask questions to the OP.